# Change the background color of a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to change the color of the background of a plot, but I am having problems in doing it. I am able to change the color of the area of the plot, but I cannot change the color of all the plot. 
Lets say I have the following data:

```
genderDistribution <- data.frame(gender = c('males','females'),
                       distribution = c(75,25))
```

Then I create the plot:

```
ggplot(genderDistribution, aes(x=gender, y=distribution)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle("Gender distribution") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray87", fill = "gray87"))
```

[image]

What I need is that all the area (including the title , axis titles) is in color `"gray87"`. How can I do this?

Comment: according to the link it should be: `+
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray87", fill = "gray87"),
          plot.background  = element_rect(colour = "gray87", fill = "gray87"))`

Comment: Thanks Andre Elrico! plot.background()